# Determine whether conditional or absolute convergence. Or if it diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given the following series:

> $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\arctan k}{k^3}$

Determine if the series diverges or converges. If it does converge, decide if it is absolute or conditional convergence.

---

Don't even think I did the absolute value correctly, I got $\frac{\pi/2}{k^3}$.

And wasn't sure what test to use on the absolute value, completely stuck on this.

Comment: What you are asking is very unclear. Please elaborate.

Comment: Is this $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\arctan k}{k^3}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\arctan k}{k^3} \leq \frac{\pi/2}{k^3}$$

$$\sum_k\frac{\pi/2}{k^3} \text{ converges } \implies \sum_k\frac{\arctan k}{k^3} \text{ converges } \implies \sum_k(-1)^k\frac{\arctan k}{k^3} \text{ converges }$$

Used Direct comparison test.

**Edit**: Use integral test to prove the convergence of first series.

Comment: Just a detail, but it should be $\frac{\arctan k}{k^3} \leq \frac{\pi/2}{k^3}$, right?

Comment: Other than using the direct comparison test, what test did you use on (pi/2)/k^3 for its convergence?

Comment: Yes. When $k = \infty$. But can $k$ ever be $\infty$. Nevertheless, strict inequality is a subset of non-strict inequality.

Comment: @cout Use integral test. $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^3}dx = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 sorry for all these questions but could you explain why you're taking the integral of 1/x^3 when the original would be (pi/2)/x^3?

Comment: Yes. That was obvious. You need to integrate $\frac{\pi/2}{x^3}$ and the integral will evaluate to $\frac{\pi/2}{2}$.